# Nginx rewrite to css factory

Tags: nginx

I have a rule which is not working correctly.

I need it so that whenever URL *xxx.com/forum/css.php* is hit, it is re-written to *xxx.com/forum/core/css.php*.
I have written the following location block for it:

```
location ~^ /forum/css.php {
    rewrite ^ /forum/core/css.php permanent;
}
```

Also needing to be taken into account is that the file is a factory so it accepts parameters, the url being hit actually looks like *xxx.com/forum/css.php?x=123&y=string*. Will this also be taken into account in the re-writes or does it need to be specified? Sorry if the question seems silly I am just beginning to work with servers! Thanks fellow coders!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rewrite a single URI (with or without query string) you could use a `location =`:

```
location = /forum/css.php {
    rewrite ^ /forum/core/css.php permanent;
}
```

The `rewrite` directive appends the query string (unless terminated with `?`). See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.